# AngularJS: ng-repeat and ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get a `<div>` when you press a button in a table row appears only for that row. But `<div>` appears in all rows.

```
<tr ng-repeat="company in companiesList">
........
<div ng-if="company.verified == 'false'">
   <input type="button" ng-class="classBtnActivar" value="ACTIVAR" ng-click="activateCompany(company.id)">
       <div style="background-color: #d1d1d1; border-radius: 100px;" ng-if="company.id == idcompany">
           <p style="text-align: center">¿Quieres activar todos los comercios de la compañía?</p>
           <div style="text-align: center">
               <input type="button" ng-class="classBtnActivar" value="SI" style="text-align: center">
               <input type="button" ng-class="classBtnActivar" value="NO" style="text-align: center">
           </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.activateCompany = function ( id ) {
    $scope.idcompany = id;
};
```

Comment: ng-if="company.verified==false", try this

Comment: i think his problem is with 2nd ng-if @tom moc

Comment: yes , may be.. @lban, provide complete code.

Comment: yes we can help out if u made a plunker iban

Comment: Can you show how does company.verified gets populated?

Comment: Simply I have a table filled with ng-repeat and in each row there is a button, when you press this button i want to be displayed into the row the second ng-if to the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your HTML structure is correct (`ng-if` inside `ng-repeat`).

Update HTML to:

```
<tr ng-repeat="company in companiesList track by $index">
  ....
  <div ng-if="!company.verified">
     <input type="button" ng-class="classBtnActivar" value="ACTIVAR" ng-click="activateCompany(company.id)">
         <div style="background-color: #d1d1d1; border-radius: 100px;" ng-if="company.id == idcompany">
             <p style="text-align: center">¿Quieres activar todos los comercios de la compañía?</p>
             <div style="text-align: center">
                 <input type="button" ng-class="classBtnActivar" value="SI" style="text-align: center">
                 <input type="button" ng-class="classBtnActivar" value="NO" style="text-align: center">
             </div>
         </div>
  </div>
</tr>
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: doesnt works!! thanks...the problem is with 2nd ng-if